# How to page a section that has multiple tables so that each page shows limited tables only in cshtml?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, paging

I have a search column which on searching shows multiple tables as results (by multiple I mean in 1000 or more) .

**Problem** - generated tables are shown in one page only, I want them to be shown in multiple pages for better readability. I also want to sort some columns of each table.

for example

in Views cshtml format I have something like this

```
 <section class="someclass"> 
 foreach(var item in something)
 {

 <table> 
    <tr>
      <td>@item.a</td>
      <td>@item.b</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>@item.c</td>
      <td>@item.d</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  }
  </section>
```

and the 'var' is generally very large in count so this code generates a lot of tables 
any idea how I could do paging in this case

what I have tried :

well I have tried table sorter and i am confused how to implement that in a section..

apart from that I don't want to use server side options as I want keep the code in javascript only.